# Cannot access windows 11 after update ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I just did an ubuntu version update this morning (from 22.10 to 23.04) via the updater software application. after that I wanted to access my windows installed on the same device. the first time I was able to access, but some files that I previously opened in ubuntu could not open. and after that my laptop went into a blue screen and kept restarting when I try to reboot.

- I have tried inserting a bootable USB to enter safe mode, but my computer cannot enter the installation menu
- I have uninstalled my ubuntu 23.04 and reinstalled ubuntu 22.04
- I've been waiting for Windows to do its own 'Preparing Automatic Repair', but the process stops halfway and returns to the blue screen and then reboots

[image: here is the blue screen that I mean]

Comment: How is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: Microsoft create a nice webpage for this error (with not much info), see: [UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7f--unexpected-kernel-mode-trap).   the real solution is re-install Ubuntu (and maybe Windows )  But first decide if you want version 23.04 or 22.04, **do not mix them, when you are a new user!!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell your PC EFI settings to boot the Ubuntu GRUB menu, not the EFI Windows boot. After booting Linux, if you do not see a Windows section in the initial grub boot menu a "sudo update-grub" command in a terminal to make sure to trigger the Windows bootloader detection mechanism of the Linux boot manager grub.